# install_github: "Error: could not find function myFun" while help(myFun) works.

Tags: r, github, devtools

I've written an R package and connected to a private repository in GitHub following the instruction in [R packages (Hadley)](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/git.html). I can successfully run the functions and visualise the help pages of the functions on when working in the .Rproj associated with the package. The package is defined by: DESCRIPTION, man, NAMESPACE, R, README.md, MyPackage.Rproj. The folder R stores the .R files and man stores the associated .Rd. I'm able to successfully install the package from the private repository using:

```
install_github(<myPackage>, auth_token=<myAuthToken>
library(<myPackage>)
```

I can succesfully read the help associated with a function  of the package using `help(<myFun>)`. However, when a try to use  I get `Error: could not find function "<myFun>"`

QUESTION: Why I cannot use the function despite having the package installed and the help working?

Comment: Have you exported the function? i.e., can you access it via `myPackage::myFun` ?

Comment: When I type `myPackage::myFun` I get `Error: myFun is not an exported object from myPackage::myFun`. I discovered that I can access the function using `:::`. Apparently I have some homework to do, thanks for pointing to the problem.

Comment: You export it in the `NAMESPACE` (look at other packages for examples). You either type it directly in the `Namespace`, or use the `@export` tag if you're using `roxygen2`.